# How To Get Count of element in List<> without linq

Tags: c#

I want to get count the elements in an array but without linq

Example:

```
string a = "cat";
string b = "dog";
string c = "cat";
string d = "horse";

var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(a);
list.Add(b);
list.Add(c);
list.Add(d);
```

And 
desired result is : cat=2, dog=1, horse=1

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why without linq? Linq is designed to make your life easier: Why would you make it harder?

Comment: `list.Count` property, otherwise loop thriugh and count in an `int`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because simply asking for code without showing any effort to solve it by the OP.

Comment: @FrankerZ `Linq` is also slow depending on the size of the data it has to iterate over and the operation that is called.

Comment: @Sach That's not a valid close reason. It's a reason to downvote, but it's not a reason to close.

Comment: @FrankerZ fair enough.

Comment: @davisj1691 But doing anything else is likely going to be a lot more costly.

Comment: my .net version cant install linq

Comment: @SuperPesucen you should make some effort to solve it and show your work here. Here's a tip to get started; iterate through the list, and see if each item matches any of strings `a`, `b` etc. If it does, increment a counter for each type.

Comment: are you going to give an example of its code?

Comment: @FrankerZ Not always, `Linq` just does a `foreach` under the hood for methods such as `Count`, `Sum`, etc. For some reason though, if you have a large list of things to compare (we're talking 300k+) then breaking down to the fundamental level is not only more simplistic but faster. This isn't true for all `Linq` methods, but most.

Comment: Does `"Cat" == "cat"` return true in your requirement?

Comment: 5 answers on a bad question :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why are you looking for LINQ less solution for this as this could be done very easily and efficiently by it. I strongly suggest you to use it and do it like below :

```
var _group = list.GroupBy(i => i);
string result = "";
foreach (var grp in _group)
   result += grp.Key + ": " + grp.Count() + Environment.NewLine;

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Otherwise you can do it like below if you really unable to use LINQ :

```
Dictionary<string, int> listCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string item in list)
    if (!listCount.ContainsKey(item))
        listCount.Add(item, 1);
    else
        listCount[item]++;

string result2 = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in listCount)
    result2 += item.Key + ": " + item.Value + Environment.NewLine;

MessageBox.Show(result2);
```

Comment: thanks my bro, this work

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way I could think of using a `Dictionary<string, int>`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetObjectCount(List<string> items)
{
    // Dictionary object to return
    Dictionary<string, int> keysAndCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    // Iterate your string values
    foreach(string s in items)
    {
        // Check if dictionary contains the key, if so, add to count
        if (keysAndCount.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            keysAndCount[s]++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add key to dictionary with initial count of 1
            keysAndCount.Add(s, 1);
        }
   }

   return keysAndCount;
}
```

Then get the result back and print to console:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = GetObjectCount(list);

//Print to Console
foreach(string s in dic.Keys)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s + " has a count of: " + dic[s]);
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a `Dictionary`? Just curious? `Linq` just counts each object under the hood and returns the result anyways.

Comment: @davisj1691 He wanted a result set, so that he could print each object type and that objects count, so by using a `Dictionary` it returns each item as a key with the count as its value. Quick lookup by key as well.

Comment: True, but consider the overhead with larger lists? Wouldn't it be more simplistic to use a count system? I can tell you an array will be faster than a dictionary with large data sets.

Comment: The OPs question appears to be homework.  I don't think blazing speed is really called for.

Comment: @davisj1691 How do you figure, a search for a key in a dictionary is o(1) and with my method, you iterate the list one time and return every item and its count. You're method returns only one specific item and its count.

Comment: @Amy True, I was honestly just curious on using a `Dictionary`. With your point in mind, a `Dictionary` seems like overkill unless it is required as part of the lesson.

Comment: I disagree, it isn't overkill *at all*.  It's a natural way of coding this exercise unless you're only counting one item in the list.

Comment: @RyanWilson I didn't take the multiple calls into account when discussing the overhead, either way it's still a very good solution.

@Amy Thank you for pointing that out. I did not know that using a `Dictionary` would be a better starting point.

Comment: @davisj1691 No problem. Nothing wrong with trying to make things more efficient, I guess I just got the idea when I saw the OP's expected results.

Comment: @RyanWilson It's a very good solution for sure, I suppose my idea came from the fact that the OP appeared to want the same result that calling `List<string>.Count(c => c == "cat")` would give.

Comment: @RyanWilson I would like you to take some time (when you are able to do so) and compare the timing between multiple calls using an array (minus the call I have to `.ToUpper` and a single call that returns the `Dictionary<string, int>`. It's not much of a difference (literally 1/10th of a second with 5,000,000 items), but using an array is faster. Not trying to be right, but I did want to test it since I felt I may have been wrong and wanted to correct myself if I was.

Comment: @davisj1691 If you did a test run, then I believe your numbers. If all they wanted was a count of one item then your method is probably faster, but it goes back to the OPs expected output, which is to show every item and its count.

Comment: @RyanWilson I completely agree with you there. Not like 1/10th of a second makes much of a difference anyways. Also wanted to point out that the difference at 100 million items was 2 seconds in favor of the `Dictionary` but at that level we are getting into `OutOfMemoryException` territory (especially when working with real data).

Comment: [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) provides better features and would be thread safe.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
public int countOccurances(List<string> inputList, string countFor)
{
    // Identifiers used are:
    int countSoFar = 0;

    // Go through your list to count
    foreach (string listItem in inputList) 
    {
       // Check your condition
       if (listItem == countFor) 
       {
           countSoFar++;
       }
    }

    // Return the results
    return countSoFar;
}
```

this will give you the count for any sting you give it. As always there is a better way but this is a good start.

Or if you want:

```
public string countOccurances(List<string> inputList, string countFor)
{
    // Identifiers used are:
    int countSoFar = 0; 
    string result = countFor;

    // Go through your list to count
    foreach (string listItem in inputList) 
    {
       // Check your condition
       if (listItem == countFor) 
       {
           countSoFar++;
       }
    }

    // Return the results
    return countFor + " = " countSoFar;
}
```

Or an even better option:

```
private static void CountOccurances(List<string> inputList, string countFor) 
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (string s in inputList)
    {
        if (s == countFor)
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {result} occurrances of {countFor}.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your issue is a [foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] { "Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "CaT", "cat", "DOG" };
Console.WriteLine($"There are {GetCount(myStrings, "cat");} cats.");
static int GetCount(string[] strings, string searchTerm) {
    int result = 0;
    foreach (string s in strings)
        if (s == searchTerm)
            result++;

    return result;
}
```

`Linq` does this under the hood. However, unless this is either for optimization of large lists or for learning experience, `Linq` should be your preferred choice if you know how to use it. It exists to make your life easier.

Another implementation of this would be to simplify the number of calls you need and just write the output in the method:

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] { "Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "CaT", "cat", "DOG" };
CountTerms(myStrings, "cat", "dog");
Console.ReadKey();

static void CountTerms(string[] strings, params string[] terms) {

    foreach (string term in terms) {
        int result = 0;
        foreach (string s in strings)
            if (s == term)
                result++;

        Console.WriteLine($"There are {result} instances of {term}");
    }
}
```

With that said, I heavily recommend Ryan Wilson's answer. His version simplifies the task at hand. The only downside to his implementation is if you are implementing this in a singular manner the way `List<string>.Count(c => c == "cat")` would.

Comment: Don't use toLower() or toUpper() because of the [Turish i Problem](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/).  Especially when `s.Equals(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` works in all cases.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The link you have included introduces a problem that has been addressed in .NET already (if I remember correctly). Feel free to look at `string.ToUpperInvariant()`. I believe `ToLower` also has the invariant version. Also, I'll be removing the `ToUpper` from my post on the grounds that it slows the comparison down quite a bit.

Comment: It's not a *problem* at all.  This is how .Net previous works, currently works, and will always work.  the `.ToUpperInvariant()` method only solves some issues as to compare correctly one should use `String.Compare(strA.ToUpperInvariant(), strB.ToUpperInvariant(), StringComparison.Ordinal);` but that's still slower than [`String.Compare(strA, strB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#the_details_of_string_comparison), so there is really no reason to use that method for comparison.

Comment: @ErikPhilips In my honest opinion, comparisons should be tested for equality without modification. I understand that there are times when modifying both the test string and the search term for comparison is useful (for example; to determine if a string contains a certain group of characters), but for the most part, if you can do `"abc" == "abc"` then do that because it's always more accurate and faster.

Comment: *determine if a string contains a certain group of characters* still does not require Toupper or ToLower (which just adds additional overhead) when one can use `strA.IndexOf(strB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`.  I see no reason to use ToUpper/ToLower.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether or not your application is available to the public and needs to take these things into account. All string comparisons are slow even without modification.

Answer (score -1):

Linq is supposed to make developer's life easy. Anyway you could make something like this:

```
        string a = "cat";
        string b = "dog";
        string c = "cat";
        string d = "horse";

        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add(a);
        list.Add(b);
        list.Add(c);
        list.Add(d);

        var result = GetCount(list);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();


 static string GetCount(List<string> obj)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            int cat = 0;
            int dog = 0;
            int horse = 0;

            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case "dog":
                        dog++;
                        break;
                    case "cat":
                        cat++;
                        break;
                    case "horse":
                        horse++;
                        break;
                }
            }

            result = "cat = " + cat.ToString() + " dog = " + dog.ToString() + " horse = " + horse.ToString();

            return result;
        }
```